# How to change Spark GroupBy/OrderBy comparator to deal with encrypted data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm doing a university work which I am trying to make Spark SQL work over encrypted data (with my algorithms). I implemented some functions that allow comparing two encrypted values in terms of their equality and order, and I am using UDF/UDAF's functions to execute these functions.

For example, if I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT count(SALARY) FROM table1 WHERE age > 20
```

I convert this one into:

```
SELECT mycount_udf(SALARY) FROM table1 WHERE myfilter_udf(greater_udf(age,20))
```

where mycount_udf, my_filter_udf and greater_udf are UDAF and UDF's implemented to deal with my functions over encrypted data.

However, I am facing a problem when I want to execute query's like ORDER BY/GROUP BY. The internals of these operators use operations of equality and order to execute the query. However, to allow to execute queries correctly over my encrypted values, I have to change the comparators inside ORDER BY/GROUP BY, in order to use my UDF comparators (equality_udf, greater_udf, etc).

If I encrypt:

```
x = 5 => encrypted_x = KSKFA92
y = 6 => encrypted_y = A9283NA
```

As 5<6, greater_udf(5,6) will return False. So I have to use this comparator inside ORDER  BY (SORT) to execute the query correctly because Spark doesn't know that the values are encrypted, and when it compares encrypted_x with encrypted_y using == or a comparator between Spark DataTypes, will cause a wrong result.

Is there any way to do this without changing Spark GROUP BY/ORDER BY source code? It seems me not possible to use UDF/UDAF. I am using JAVA to do this work.